# Android 6 on screen keyboard not enabled

Tags: keyboard

When using the Android 6 (Moto G2) only the voice option was given for user input.
A device reboot failed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Device, Apps

In an effort to save space the user had disabled Google gboard in error as well Google Hindi Input, Google Korean Input etc

Comment: I'm confused. Are you answering your question? Or are you telling us what happened?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, answering the question.